# How to use number formatter within a function?

Tags: ios, swift

hello everyone I am fairly new to swift and i need to use number formatter when i am setting text on a UILabel to show a decimal to 2 places however i get this error... *Value of type 'NumberFormatter' has no member 'String'* can anyone show me how to do it the right way?

```
func theseAretheFunctions() {


        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        if reactionVolumeInt == 50{


        bufferVolumeLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSamples)! * 10)
        dNTPsVolumeLabel.text = numberOfSamples
        forwardPrimerLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSamples)! * 2.5)
        reversePrimerLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSamples)! * 2.5)
        dnaPolymeraseLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSamples)! * 0.5)
        }
        else if reactionVolumeInt == 20{
            bufferVolumeLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSamples)! * 4)
            dNTPsVolumeLabel.text = formatter.String(Double(numberOfSamples)! * 0.4)// This is where i get the error.
            forwardPrimerLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSamples)! * 1)
            reversePrimerLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSamples)! * 1)
            dnaPolymeraseLabel.text = String(Double(numberOfSamples)! * 0.2)



        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
dNTPsVolumeLabel.text = formatter.string(from:Double(numberOfSamples)! * 0.4)
```